# Fixed Bars are not floating with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please have a look at following link, I am having a very weird problem. I made some call to action floating divs for mobile which should move with the scroll but for some reason its not working fine and floating in default or old browsers of cell phone like P8 or iPhone 5.

I tried various work around but they  doesn't seem to fix the problem. Can anyone please suggest something so my floating divs should work across all browsers?

```
#fstickyfor_mobile {
position: fixed; 
position: device-fixed;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
display:block;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

[Check this Link](http://webuyanyhouse.net/)

Comment: Why are you overwriting `position` ?

Comment: @msanford I read it somewhere that it may fix the problem: position: device-fixed;

Comment: That may be the case; what I meant was that only the last one will be applied.